# How to add shell expansions inside a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For example:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
ex:
    echo $RANDOM
```

When you invoke it:

```
$ make ex
echo ANDOM
ANDOM
```

What is happening there? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make interprets the $ sign as its own variable (R, in your case). You need to escape it:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
ex:
    echo $$RANDOM
```

Answer (score 0):

$(RANDOM) If I remember correctly is the correct makefile syntax

Edit: $(RANDOM) is for Makefile variables.

If you have an exported shell variable, you'll need to use ${RANDOM}

Comment: No. `$(VAR)` and `${VAR}` are both valid `make` syntax. The problem here is that `make` is expanding `$R` to the empty string (see the first answer).